# Wrapper function in PowerShell: Pass remaining parameters

Tags: powershell, parameters

I’m trying to write a wrapper function in PowerShell that basically evaluates the first parameter and based on that runs a program on the computer. All the remaining parameters to the wrapper function should then be passed to the program that is ran as well.

So it should look something like this:

```
function test ( [string] $option )
{
    if ( $option -eq 'A' )
    {
        Write-Host $args
    }
    elseif ( $option -eq 'B' )
    {
        . 'C:\Program Files\some\program.exe' $args
    }
}
```

Now just adding `$args` does not work, so what do I have to do to make it work? Another option would probably be using `Invoke-Expression`, but it feels a bit like `eval` so I want to avoid if possible, and in addition I think doing it like that would limit me to string-only parameters right? If possible I would want to have the full support for the wrapped program/cmdlet - basically like a dynamic alias. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This sort of does what you ask.  You may run into trouble if you need to pass dash-prefixed options to the executable that conflict or cause ambiguity with the PowerShell common parameters.  But this may get you started.

```
function Invoke-MyProgram
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [parameter(mandatory=$true, position=0)][string]$Option,
        [parameter(mandatory=$false, position=1, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]$Remaining
    )

    if ($Option -eq 'A')
    {
        Write-Host $Remaining
    }
    elseif ($Option -eq 'B')
    {
        & 'C:\Program Files\some\program.exe' @Remaining # NOTE: @ not $ (splatting)
    }
}
```

Comment: While recommending splatting is the crucial pointer for enabling support for passing through arguments to any (type of) command, _array_ (list)-based splatting, as in your solution, is limited to _positional_ (unnamed) parameter passing to other PowerShell commands, which is a severe limitation. Due to built-in magic, using a non-advanced function with `@args` - even though the _automatic_ `$args` variable is also an array - does _not_ have this limitation. To also support _named_ parameter pass-through in an _advanced_ function (such as yours), more work is needed.

Answer (score 7):

- **Your solution works as-is for *external programs*** (such as your `C:\Program Files\some\program.exe` example): you can always **pass an *array* of values** (which is what `$args` is) **to an external program**, and its **elements will be passed as *individual arguments*** (stringified, if necessary).
- **You can make your solution work with *any* command if you change `$args` to `@args`**<sup>[1]</sup>, to take advantage of a PowerShell parameter-passing technique called [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting):

```bsh
function test ( [string] $option )
{
    if ( $option -eq 'A' )
    {
        Write-Host $args
    }
    elseif ( $option -eq 'B' )
    {
        # Use @args to also support passing *named* arguments
        # through to *PowerShell* commands.
        & $someCommand @args
    }
}
```

**Caveats**:

- The **[automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args), which collects all arguments for which *no* parameter was declared, is only available in *simple* (non-advanced) functions and scripts**; [*advanced* functions and scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) - those that use the `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute and/or  `[Parameter()]` attributes - require that *all* potential parameters be declared.
- **PowerShell has *built-in magic* that makes the automatic *array* variable `$args` also support passing *named* parameters through via splatting**, which no *custom* array or collection supports.

  - By contrast, **custom arrays and collections only support splatting *positional* (unnamed) arguments**, which, however, covers all calls to *external programs*.
  - **When calling *PowerShell* commands, this limitation is problematic**, however: For instance, if you wanted to pass the *named* argument `-Path C:\` through to the `Set-Location` cmdlet via splatting, using a custom collection parameter declared via `ValueFromRemaining Arguments`, as shown in [OldFart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7418440/45375) (`Set-Location @Remaining`), would *not* work; **to support passing through *named* arguments (other than via `@args`, if available), you must use *hashtable*-based splatting**.

Therefore, **if your function is an *advanced* one *and* you need to support passing *named* arguments through to other PowerShell commands, a different approach is required**: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62622638/45375) shows two alternatives.

---

<sup>[1] With *external programs*, there is a corner case where `@args` behaves differently from `$args`, namely if the `$args` array contains `--%`, the [stop-parsing symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing): `@args` recognizes it, `$args` treats it as a literal.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

What you have written does work. Note that what is there is  `$args` is the unnamed arguments that are over and above the parameters expected by the function.

So if you call test as

```
test -option "A" 1 2 3
```

`$args` will have `1,2,3`

Note that if you call test as

```
test -option "A" -other "B" 1 2 3
```

`$args` will have `-other,B,1,2,3`

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to improve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7418440) answer and suggest a solution that works both for positional and named arguments:

```
function Invoke-MyProgram
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [parameter(mandatory=$true, position=0)][string]$Option,
        [parameter(mandatory=$false, position=1, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]$Remaining
    )

    if ($Option -eq 'A')
    {
        Write-Host $Remaining
    }
    elseif ($Option -eq 'B')
    {
        Invoke-Expression "& `"C:\Program Files\some\program.exe`" $Remaining"
    }
}
```

**Caution**: [Be aware](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/) of the security issues of 'Invoke-Expression'!