# PowerShell Functions and varying parameters

Tags: function, powershell, arguments

Early on in my script I have check to define whether a parameter "-Silent" was used when running the script. The idea is to have zero output from the script if it was and it will be checked on every Write-Host entry I have later. It seems a bit heavy to make if-else statements on *every* single Write-Host I have, so I decided to go with a function - something like this:

```
Function Silent-Write ([string]$arg1)
    {
        if ($silent -eq $false) {
            if ($args -ieq "-nonewline") {
                Write-Host "$arg1" -NoNewLine
            }
        elseif ($args -ieq "-foregroundcolor") {
            Write-Host "$arg1" -ForegroundColor $args
            }
        else {
            Write-Host "$arg1"
        }
    }
}

Silent-Write -ForegroundColor red "hello"
```

This is not working, but you get the idea; besides passing the text I want to output, Silent-Write function should also take other Write-Host arguments into consideration. Quite simple issue I believe, but something I cannot figure out with the knowledge of functions I have.

Comment: Which PowerShell version you use?

Comment: Looks a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415883/wrapper-function-in-powershell-pass-remaining-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell V3 you can use splatting:

```powershell
Function Silent-Write
{
    if (!$silent) {
        Write-Host @args
    }
}

Silent-Write -ForegroundColor red "hello"
```