# Wrapper function for cmdlet - pass remaining parameters

Tags: powershell, parameters, wrapper

I'm writing a function that wraps a cmdlet using ValueFromRemainingArguments (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415883/wrapper-function-in-powershell-pass-remaining-parameters)).

The following simple code demonstrates the problem:

- works

```bsh
function Test-WrapperArgs {
    Set-Location @args
}
```

```
Test-WrapperArgs -Path C:\
```

- does not work

```bsh
function Test-WrapperUnbound {
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)] $UnboundArgs
    )

    Set-Location @UnboundArgs
}
```

```
Test-WrapperUnbound -Path C:\
Set-Location: F:\cygwin\home\thorsten\.config\powershell\test.ps1:69
Line |
  69 |      Set-Location @UnboundArgs
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:\'.
```

I tried getting to the issue with `GetType` and `EchoArgs` from the [PowerShell Community Extensions](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx) to no avail. At the moment I'm almost considering a bug (maybe related to [this ticket](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2035)??).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **best solution for an *advanced* function** (one that uses a `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute and/or a `[Parameter()]` attribute) is to **scaffold a proxy (wrapper) function via the PowerShell SDK**, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55539863/45375).
This involves essentially *duplicating* the target command's parameter declarations (albeit in an automatic, but static fashion).

**If you do *not* want to use this approach, your only option is to *perform your own parsing* of the `$UnboundArgs` array** (technically, it is an instance of `[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]`), which is cumbersome, however, and not foolproof:

```
function Test-WrapperUnbound {
  Param(
      [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)] $UnboundArgs
  )

  # (Incompletely) emulate PowerShell's own argument parsing by 
  # building a hashtable of parameter-argument pairs to pass through
  # to Set-Location via splatting.
  $htPassThruArgs = @{}; $key = $null
  switch -regex ($UnboundArgs) {
    '^-(.+)' { if ($key) { $htPassThruArgs[$key] = $true } $key = $Matches[1] }
    default {  $htPassThruArgs[$key] = $_; $key = $null }
  }
  if ($key) { $htPassThruArgs[$key] = $true } # trailing switch param.

  # Pass the resulting hashtable via splatting.
  Set-Location @htPassThruArgs

}
```

Note:

- This isn't foolproof in that your function won't be able to distinguish between an actual parameter name (e.g., `-Path`) and a string literal that happens to look like a parameter name (e.g., `'-Path'`)
- Also, unlike with the scaffolding-based proxy-function approach mentioned at the top, you won't get tab-completion for any pass-through parameters and the pass-through parameters won't be listed with `-?` / `Get-Help` / `Get-Command -Syntax`.

**If you don't mind having neither tab-completion nor syntax help and/or your wrapper function must support pass-through to *multiple* or *not-known-in-advance* target commands, using a *simple* (non-advanced) function with `@args`** (as in your working example; see also below) **is the simplest option**, assuming your function doesn't *itself* need to support [common parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters) (which requires an *advanced* function).
Using a *simple* function also implies that common parameters are passed through to the wrapped command *only* (whereas an *advanced* function would interpret them as meant for *itself*, though their effect [*usually*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4568) propagates to calls inside the function; with a common parameter such as `-OutVariable`, however, the distinction matters).

---

As for **what you tried**:

While **PowerShell does support [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) via *arrays*** (or array-like collections such as `[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]`) in principle, this **only works as intended if all elements are to be passed as *positional* arguments and/or if the target command is an *external program*** (about whose parameter structure PowerShell knows nothing, and always passes arguments as a list/array of tokens).

**In order to pass arguments with *named parameters* to other PowerShell commands, you must use *hashtable*-based splatting**, where each entry's key identifies the target *parameter* and the value the parameter *value* (argument).

Even though the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) is technically also an *array* (`[object[]]`), **PowerShell has *built-in magic* that allows splatting with `@args` to also work with named parameters** - this does *not* work with any custom array or collection.

Note that the automatic **`$args`** variable, which collects all arguments for which *no* parameter was declared - is **only available in *simple* (non-advanced) functions and scripts**; [*advanced* functions and scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) - those that use the `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute and/or  `[Parameter()]` attributes - require that *all* potential parameters be declared.

Comment: Very useful on the point explanation regarding the difference between splatting arrays and hashtables and the special case for params in simple and advanced functions. In my case I can actually use `@args` because it does not contain all arguments but only those not assigned (using a simple function). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @mkelement0 is there a reason why ValueFromRemainingArguments *couldn't* be constructed in a way that it would behave the same as $args for splatting purposes? Seems like that would solve this problem, I couldn't find an issue in the PS repo as a request for this, maybe there's a good reason you can enlighten me to.

Comment: @JustinGrote: That sounds like a nice enhancement; I'm not aware of an existing feature request to that effect, so I encourage you to create one (and let us know here - I'd be happy to include a link in the answer).