# PowerShell pass all parameters received in function, and handle parameters with spaces

Tags: function, powershell, parameters, variadic-functions

I am a novice with PowerShell.
In Msys2 (or Lnux), I have defined a function `npp`

```
npp ()
{
    ${NPP_PATH} "$@"
}
```

such that if I call from the command prompt `npp` it launches Notepad++ (as defined in `${NPP_PATH}`).
If I call `npp "mydir/stage 1/a.txt"` it opens that file for editing.
Generally speaking, it allows:

1. Any number of parameters.
2. Parameters containing spaces, if suitably escaped.

**What would be the equivalent in PowerShell?**

I guess in PS I should also go for a function to obtain a similar behavior.
So far, I could receive an undefined number of parameters, and use them in a `foreach` loop, see code below.
But I could not find the equivalent of the simple `"$@"` to pass all parameters as they are received.
Moreover, if I use quotes in one of the arguments, they are removed, so it will probably have problems with file paths including blanks.

```
function multi_params {
    param(
        [Parameter(
            ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true
        )][string[]]
        $listArgs
    )
    $count = 0
    foreach($listArg in $listArgs) {
        '$listArgs[{0}]: {1}' -f $count, $listArg
        $count++
    }
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Assuming that `NPP_PATH` is an *environment* variable, the equivalent PowerShell function is:

```
function npp {
  & $env:NPP_PATH $args
}
```

<sup>If `NPP_PATH` is the name of a regular PowerShell variable, use `& $NPP_PATH $args`.</sup>

`&` is the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), which is needed for *syntactic* reasons whenever you want to invoke a command whose name/path is specified in *quotes* and/or via a *variable*.

In [*simple* functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions#simple-functions) (as opposed to [*advanced* functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced?view=powershell-7.1)) such as the above (use of neither  `[CmdletBinding()]` nor `[Parameter()]` attributes), you can use the [automatic **`$args`** variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables) to pass any arguments through to another command.

- If the target command is not an *external program*, such as here, but a *PowerShell* command, use the form **`@args`** to ensure that all arguments - including those preceded by their *parameter names* - are properly passed through - see [about_Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting).
  Note that the form `@args` works with external programs too, where it is *generally* equivalent to `$args` (the only difference is that only `@args` recognizes and removes [`--%`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#the-stop-parsing-token), the stop-parsing token)
- Note that passing arguments with *embedded `"`* chars. and *empty arguments* to *external programs* is still broken as of PowerShell v7.0 - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375).

---

#### Passing arguments through in *simple* vs. *advanced* functions (scripts):

- **In *simple* functions** only, `$args` contains all arguments that did not bind to *declared* parameters, if any, on invocation.

  - If your simple function *doesn't* declare *any* parameters, as in the example above, `$args` contains *all* arguments passed on invocation.
  - If your simple function *does* declare parameters (typically via `param(...)`), `$args` contains only those *arguments that didn't bind to declared parameters*; in short: it collects any arguments your function did not declare parameters for.
  - Therefore, `$args` is a simple mechanism for collecting arguments not declared or known in advance, either to be used in the function itself - notably if declaring parameters isn't worth the effort - or to pass those arguments through to another command.
  - To pass arguments that comprise *named* arguments (e.g., `-Path foo` instead of just `foo`) through to another PowerShell command, *splatting* is needed, i.e. the form `@args`.

    - Note that while `$args` is technically a regular PowerShell array (`[object[]]`), it also has built-in magic to support passing named arguments through; a *custom array* can *not* be used for this, and the *hash-table* form of splatting is then required - see [about_Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting)
- **In *advanced* functions**, `$args` is *not* available, because *advanced functions by definition only accept arguments for which parameters have been declared*.

  - To accept extra, *positional-only* arguments, you must define a catch-all `ValueFromRemainingArguments` parameter, as shown in the question, which collects such arguments in an array-like<sup>[1]</sup> data structure by default.
  - To also support *named* pass-through arguments, you have two basic option:

    - If you *know* the set of potential pass-through parameters, *declare them as part of your own function*.

      - You can then use splatting with the `$PSBoundParameters` dictionary (hash table) - see below - to pass named arguments through, possibly after removing arguments meant for your function itself from the dictionary.
    - This technique is used when writing *proxy (wrapper)* functions for existing commands; the PowerShell SDK makes duplicating the pass-through parameters easier by allowing you to *scaffold* a proxy function based on an existing command - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55539863/45375).
  - Otherwise, there is only a suboptimal solution where you emulate PowerShell's own parameter parsing to parse the positional arguments into parameter-name/value pairs - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62622638/45375).

---

The **[automatic `$PSBoundParameters` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psboundparameters)** is a dictionary that is available in *both* simple and advanced functions:

- `$PSBoundParameters` applies only if your function declares parameters, and **contains entries only for those *among the declared parameters* to which arguments were actually bound (passed) on invocation**; the dictionary keys are the parameter names, albeit without the initial `-`.
  Note that parameters bound *by a default value* are *not* included - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3285) for a discussion.
  Again, note that in *advanced* functions you can only pass a given argument if a parameter was declared for it, so any argument passed in a given invocation is by definition reflected in `$PSBoundParameters`.
- Because it is a dictionary (hash table), it can be used with hash-table based splatting - `@PSBoundParameters` - to pass named arguments through to other PowerShell commands and, since it is *mutable*, you have the option of *adding* or *removing* named arguments (such as the ones intended for your function *itself*).

---

<sup>[1] That type is [`[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1); however, you can specify a collection type explicitly, such as `[object[]]` to get a regular PowerShell array.</sup>