# How to splat Powershell arguments in the same manner that Python *args, **kwargs work

Tags: python, powershell, arguments, keyword-argument, parameter-splatting

Both python and powershell support a form of splatting array and named arguments as function inputs, a very useful feature.

However powershell seem to be internally inconsistent somewhat.
I am trying to reproduce powershell code that behaves similarly to the following python code:

```py
def echoName(Name, *args, **kwargs):
    print("Name is:", Name)


def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    print("args:", args)
    print("kwargs:", kwargs)
    echoName(*args, **kwargs)

d = {
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": 25
}
wrapper(**d)
# args: ()
# kwargs: {'Name': 'John', 'Age': 25}
# Name is: John
```

As far as I am aware `ValueFromRemainingArguments` is the only way to accept left over parameters in a powershell advanced function

```
function echoName { 
    param(
        [CmdletBinding()]
        [string]$Name,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $False, ValueFromRemainingArguments = $True)]
        [Object[]] $Arguments
    )
    Write-Host "Name is: $Name"
}
function wrapper {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory = $False, ValueFromRemainingArguments = $True)]
        [Object[]] $Arguments
    )
    Write-Host "Arguments is: $Arguments"
    echoName @Arguments

}
$d = @{
    Name = 'John'
    Age  = 25
}
wrapper @d
# Arguments is: -Name: John -Age: 25
# Name is: -Name:
```

I have 3 issues with powershell's output

1. Arguments is now an array
2. the named arguments were prefixed with `-` and suffixed with `:`
3. this is a weird behavior at best:

```
$a = @(1,2,3)
wrapper @a @d
# Arguments is: 1 2 3 -Name: John -Age: 25
# Name is: 1
```

How can I chain and only partially consume variables as possible in python?

[What is the difference between a cmdlet and a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51911385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-cmdlet-and-a-function/51912471#51912471fu)
[Wrapper function for cmdlet - pass remaining parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62622385/wrapper-function-for-cmdlet-pass-remaining-parametersnction/51912471#51912471)
[Is there a way to create an alias to a cmdlet in a way that it only runs if arguments are passed to the alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55539278/is-there-a-way-to-create-an-alias-to-a-cmdlet-in-a-way-that-it-only-runs-if-argu/55539863#55539863)

Comment: Change your wrapper to `function wrapper { Write-Host "Args are '$args'";echoName @args }`. Removing the param block and CmdletBinding attribute will cause PowerShell to start passing the argument values as-is, without attempting any validation or type coercion during binding.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen what if I must use CmdletBinding?

Comment: Then you have two options, either 1) explicitly declare the parameters you want to forward and then call `echoName @PSBoundParameters` from the wrapper, or 2) accept a dictionary instance and splat that, eg. `param([System.Collections.IDictionary]$kwArgs) echoName @kwArgs` (original call needs to be `wrapper $dict` instead of `wrapper @dict` then)

Comment: so either use IDictionary that's not general and breaks when wrapper has more parameters or I must know the echoName parameters in advance?

Comment: I fail to see how it "breaks when wrapper has more parameters"? You can define any additional parameters for the wrapper function itself, and you can stuff as many entries into the dictionary as you like. What exact use are you _not_ able to solve/support?

Comment: I found this oddity of splatting when working with Pester actually... InModuleScope blocks can accept -Parameters, a hashtable, and -ArgumentList, an array, and they behave exactly as described in the original post, with $args having extra items based on Parameters.
I think it's reasonable to expect a similar splatting behavior like python's so I want to understand how to avoid the naive powershell splatting behavior in my own scripts when chaining calls together. I find it weird that there is a difference in calling `func -Param 'val'` and `$d = @{Param ='val'}; func @d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desire is for a function to support accepting open-ended pass-through arguments and to pass them on to a different PowerShell command as *named* arguments, i.e. as *parameter name-value pairs*.

Fundamentally, **PowerShell's [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting)** supports passing named arguments only within the following *constraints*:

- The **caller** must use a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) whose entries are the parameter name-value pairs.
- The **callee** must have *explicit, individual* parameters whose names match the entry keys of the hashtable.

  - When name-matching, PowerShell's "elastic syntax" applies: If a hashtable entry is an *unambiguous prefix* of the target parameter name, binding succeeds (e.g. an `N` entry in your example would bind to parameter `-Name`, as long as there are no other parameters whose name starts with `N`). For long-term stability, however, this convenience is *best avoided*.
- If the input hashtable has entries that do *not* match parameters of the callee:

  - They are passed as extra, *positional* arguments, with each name-value pair becoming *two* arguments: the name itself in a way that makes it *look* like the parameter part of a named argument (e.g. `'-Name:'`) and the value as a separate argument (e.g. `'John'`)
  - If the callee is a *simple* (non-advanced) function or script, these extra positional arguments are collected in the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) variable.
  - If the callee is an *[advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced)* function or script, the only way to receive these extra positional arguments is to explicitly define a catch-all parameter - which invariably only supports *positional* arguments - via the `ValueFromRemainingArguments` parameter-attribute property, as shown in your question. Without that, an *error* would occur, because advanced functions by design prevent unrecognized arguments from getting passed.

---

The automatic `$args` variable - despite being an *array* rather than a hashtable - has *built-in magic* that allows you to pass its positionally collected arguments on *as named arguments* (assuming the callee is a PowerShell command).

However, no *custom* array supports this, so if you do need an *advanced* function - which makes `$args` unavailable - your only option is to *reconstruct a hashtable* from the `ValueFromRemainingArguments` array's elements and use the result for splatting; however, this is not only cumbersome, but cannot be done *fully robustly* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62622638/45375) for an implementation and more information.

---

**In your specific case**, I suggest doing using a *mix* of splatting and passing (possibly *ordered*) hashtables *directly*:

```bash
# Expects -Name as a direct argument and an 
# -Arguments hashtable with additional name-value pairs.
function echoName { 
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [string]$Name,
    [System.Collections.IDictionary] $Arguments
  )
  Write-Verbose -Verbose "echoName: -Name is:"
  $Name
  Write-Verbose -Verbose "echoName: -Arguments is:"
  $Arguments
}

# Expects just a hashtable, which it passes through to
# echoName *via a splatting*
function wrapper {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [System.Collections.IDictionary] $Arguments
  )
  Write-Verbose -Verbose "wrapper: -Arguments is: "
  $Arguments
  echoName @Arguments
}

# Construct an ordered hashtable (dictionary) of name-value pairs.
$d = [ordered] @{
  Name = 'John'
  # Nested hashtable to ultimately pass to echoName's -Arguments
  Arguments = @{
    Age  = 25
  }
}

# Pass it *as-is* to wrapper - don't use splatting here.
wrapper $d
```

Display output:

[image: screenshot of output]