# Create a wrapper for functions in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, parameters

I want to wrap a function, that is to create a new function such that it would automatically pass some arguments to the old function, like Python's `partial` functions. The arguments passed are the ones defined in the callee and not the caller. The important thing is that I don't want to refer to  each of them explicitly (define them twice).

That is really done to save typing-in the same flags to complicated functions while allowing customization.

For example, in Python, I would do:

```
call_with_x=partial(call,x=1)
```

Or maybe use `**kw` and pass it to the callee in some cases.

---

This is my best try (based on *[Wrapper function in PowerShell: Pass remaining parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415883/wrapper-function-in-powershell-pass-remaining-parameters)*):

```
function Let
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
Param([parameter(mandatory=$true, position=0)][string]$Option,
    [parameter(mandatory=$false, position=1, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]$Remaining)
Get @Remaining
}

function Get
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
        Param([parameter(mandatory=$false, position=0)][string]$OptionA,
[parameter(mandatory=$true, position=1)][string]$OptionB)
Write-Host $OptionA, $OptionB
}
```

But `Let -Option c -OptionA 1`

Prints `-OptionA 1`
which is obviously not what I intended.

Comment: What is the intentions? You would only get `-OptionA 1` cause you're only splatting that parameter. Maybe I'm not understanding what you're asking for, but you can splat all the parameters using `@PSBoundParameters`. The only issue would be that the "*callee*" function would have to have the same parameters as the caller function.

Comment: I would like the callee to have its optionA and optionB filled by args supplied to the caller. Notice that they don't have the same signature.  `PSBoundParameters` seems like a good direction.

Comment: The remaining kind of absorbs all args. it seems to be the only problem. But solveable I guess. I didnt know that variable.

Comment: Perhaps it is possible to use DynamicParam  to add the reamining parameters of the sec function.

Comment: Unfortunately `ValueFromRemainingArguments` produces an array, but for forwarding using splatting, you'd need a hashtable. You could start with `$PSBoundParameters` and remove the arguments that shouldn't be forwarded.

Comment: if you define `$Remaining` as `[hashtable]` without a need for `ValueFromRemainingArguments` then `Get @Remaining` would work without problems as long as the hashtable being passed as argument has Keys matching the parameters form `Get`. This would also mean when calling `let` you're actually building a hash with the parameters as Keys...

Comment: the `DynamicParam` idea is not bad either, you could build the remaining parameters at runtime by reading the AST of `Get` (untested but I think that should work)

Comment: `(Get-Command Get).Parameters` gives you all the parameters without the need for the AST.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That was hard!
For this you would need to add a bit of code in DynmaicParams and begin section of the function.

It might be possible to do it in an Attribute

```
function x{
[WrapperFor(y)]
```

Might do it Later.

```
function Get
{
    [CmdLetBinding()]
        Param([parameter(mandatory=$false, position=0)][string]$OptionA,
[parameter(mandatory=$false, position=1)][string]$OptionB)
Write-Host "opta",$OptionA
Write-Host "optb",$OptionB
}


function Let
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
Param([parameter(mandatory=$true, position=0)][string]$Option,[parameter(mandatory=$false, position=0)][string]$OptionB)


DynamicParam {
AddWrapper -For "Get" -To "Let"
}
Begin { 
    
   $params = GetRestOfParams "Get" $PSBoundParameters
}
Process {
    Get @params 
}
}
```

Needed code:

```
using namespace System.Management.Automation
function Empt
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
        Param([parameter(mandatory=$true, position=0)][string]$aaaa)
    1
}

function AddWrapper([parameter(mandatory=$true, position=0)][string]$For,[parameter(mandatory=$true, position=1)][string]$To) 
{
    $paramDictionary = [RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary]::new()
    $paramset= $(Get-Command $For).Parameters.Values | %{[System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter]::new($_.Name,$_.ParameterType,$_.Attributes)}
    $paramsetlet= $(Get-Command empt).Parameters.Keys 
    $paramsetlet+= $(Get-Command $To).ScriptBlock.Ast.Body.ParamBlock.Parameters.Name | %{ $_.VariablePath.UserPath }
    $paramset | %{ if ( -not ($paramsetlet -contains $_.Name) ) {$paramDictionary.Add($_.Name,$_)}}
    return $paramDictionary
}
function GetRestOfParams($dst,$params)
{
    $dstorgparams=$(Get-Command $dst).Parameters.Keys
    $z= $params
    $z.Keys | %{ if ( -not ($dstorgparams -contains $_) ) {$z.Remove($_)} } | Out-Null
    return $z
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't require "advanced" function features from [CmdletBinding()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute), then you can get away with using `$args` for this:

```sh
# simple function parameters are positional and named, but not mandatory
function let {
  Param($OptionA,$OptionB)

  write-host "OptionA=$OptionA"
  write-host "OptionB=$OptionB"

  get @args
}

function get {
  Param($OptionC,$OptionD)

  write-host "OptionC=$OptionC"
  write-host "OptionD=$OptionD"
}

# not necessary to name or include parameters
let -OptionA A B -OptionC C D

OptionA=A
OptionB=B
OptionC=C
OptionD=D

# named parameters get assigned first, so the order is not too big a deal either
# these produce the same results as above:
let B -OptionA A D -OptionC C 
let -OptionD D -OptionC C A B
```

Any named parameters will not get positionally assigned to `let`

Any additional parameters, named or otherwise, will be forwarded to `get`

Comment: My functions are more complicated . But it is nice suggestion.